# Convergence of a certain series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a set, $\lambda_{i} > 0, i \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $\phi_{i}: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}, i \in \mathbb{N}$,  be linearly independent functions.

Let
\begin{equation}\label{ref{eq:mercer}}
k(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_{i}\phi_{i}(x) \phi_{i}(y)
\end{equation}
be a function, where the convergence fulfills some criteria, for example being absolute and pointwise. Consider the set of functions

$$A = \{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_{i}\phi_{i} \mid \alpha_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_{i}^{2}}{\lambda_{i}} < \infty\} $$

Is this set well defined? For example; does the series for $f \in A$ converge? If not, what do we need to assume, in order to achieve well-definedness/convergence?

Im trying to patchwork together a number of different theorems into one of my own, but am not sure about the above questions.

I would appreciate any suggestions/answers very much! Thank you.